# Alert when high or low crosses the top or bottom box

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I am trying to set an alert when the high or low of the candle crosses the top red or bottom green bar. The problem is that I'm not very familiar with functions and I have a hard time addressing the bottom line or top line of the box by a name. In the lower indicator, I'm not sure where I can intervene to implement a cross() with the upper or lower line of the box. I tried to assign a name in the function for the box.

Unfortunately I get an error message. So how can I get the coordinates of the box?

[image: Here is a screenshot]

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='Test 69 - Bagang Pivot Zones', overlay=true)

// functions
get(arr, index) =>
    index < array.size(arr) ? array.get(arr, index) : na

busted(highs, lows, times, bounces) =>
    array.shift(highs)
    array.shift(lows)
    array.shift(times)
    array.shift(bounces) or true

bounced(bounces) =>
    status = array.get(bounces, 0)
    array.set(bounces, 0, true)
    status

// A. CORE
ceiling = math.max(high, close[1], open[1])
floor = math.min(low, close[1], open[1])

buying = close >= open and high != low
selling = close <= open and low != high

green = close > open and close > close[1]
red = close < open and close < close[1]

gapup = open > close[1]
gapdown = open < close[1]

higher = high > high[1]
lower = low < low[1]

bullish = green and higher
bearish = red and lower

// notable price actions
bullishEngulf = selling[1] and (gapdown or lower) and bullish and close > open[1]
bearishEngulf = buying[1] and (gapup or higher) and bearish and close < open[1]

breakHigh = (selling[2] or selling[1]) and buying and close > ceiling[1]
breakLow = (buying[2] or buying[1]) and selling and close < floor[1]

whiteSoldiers = bearish[3] and buying[2] and bullish[1] and bullish and close > high[3]
blackCrows = bullish[3] and selling[2] and bearish[1] and bearish and close < low[3]

// pivot setups
soaring = bullishEngulf or breakHigh or whiteSoldiers
tumbling = bearishEngulf or breakLow or blackCrows

reversal = switch
    whiteSoldiers => not soaring[1] and not soaring[2]
    blackCrows => not tumbling[1] and not tumbling[2]
    breakHigh => not soaring[1] and (bearish[1] or bearish[2])
    breakLow => not tumbling[1] and (bullish[1] or bullish[2])

continuation = switch
    breakHigh => bullish[2] and close > high[2] and not bearish[1]
    breakLow => bearish[2] and close < low[2] and not bullish[1]

engulfing = (bullishEngulf or bearishEngulf) and (higher[1] or lower[1])

// B. PIVOT ZONES
var buyzoneHigh = array.new_float(0)
var buyzoneLow = array.new_float(0)
var buyzoneTime = array.new_int(0)
var bounceUp = array.new_bool(0)

var sellzoneHigh = array.new_float(0)
var sellzoneLow = array.new_float(0)
var sellzoneTime = array.new_int(0)
var bounceDown = array.new_bool(0)

// 1. Broken Pivot Zones
brokenHigh = while get(sellzoneHigh, 0) < high
    busted(sellzoneHigh, sellzoneLow, sellzoneTime, bounceDown)

brokenLow = while get(buyzoneLow, 0) > low
    busted(buyzoneHigh, buyzoneLow, buyzoneTime, bounceUp)

// 2. Distribution/Accumulation Bar and Pivot Bar
upturn = soaring and (reversal or continuation or engulfing)
downturn = tumbling and (reversal or continuation or engulfing)

dacbar = switch
    upturn => whiteSoldiers ? 3 : (breakHigh and selling[2] ? 2 : 1)
    downturn => blackCrows ? 3 : (breakLow and buying[2] ? 2 : 1)

pivotbar = switch
    upturn => whiteSoldiers ? 2 : (green[1] ? 1 : 0)
    downturn => blackCrows ? 2 : (red[1] ? 1 : 0)

// 3. Pivot Zone Values
pzHigh = float(na)
pzLow = float(na)

switch
    upturn =>
        // low at wick
        pzLow := math.min(low[dacbar], low[pivotbar], low[1], low)
        // high at wick or open
        pzHigh := switch
            close[pivotbar] > high[dacbar] => high[dacbar]
            open[pivotbar] > open[dacbar] => open[pivotbar]
            => open[dacbar]

    downturn =>
        // high at wick
        pzHigh := math.max(high[dacbar], high[pivotbar], high[1], high)
        // low at wick or open
        pzLow := switch
            close[pivotbar] < low[dacbar] => low[dacbar]
            open[pivotbar] < open[dacbar] => open[pivotbar]
            => open[dacbar]

// 4. Overlapping Pivot Zones
overlap = switch
    upturn => get(buyzoneHigh, 0) >= pzLow
    downturn => get(sellzoneLow, 0) <= pzHigh

replace = switch
    overlap and upturn => bounced(bounceUp)
    overlap and downturn => bounced(bounceDown)

// remove replaced zone or adjust overlapped zone
switch
    replace and upturn => busted(buyzoneHigh, buyzoneLow, buyzoneTime, bounceUp)
    replace and downturn => busted(sellzoneHigh, sellzoneLow, sellzoneTime, bounceDown)
    overlap and upturn => array.set(buyzoneHigh, 0, pzLow)
    overlap and downturn => array.set(sellzoneLow, 0, pzHigh)

// 5. Pivot Zones Queue
switch
    upturn =>
        array.unshift(buyzoneHigh, pzHigh)
        array.unshift(buyzoneLow, pzLow)
        array.unshift(buyzoneTime, time[dacbar])
        array.unshift(bounceUp, false)

    downturn =>
        array.unshift(sellzoneHigh, pzHigh)
        array.unshift(sellzoneLow, pzLow)
        array.unshift(sellzoneTime, time[dacbar])
        array.unshift(bounceDown, false)

// 6. Pivot Zones Markup
maxbox(redraw) => redraw ? 22 : na

newbox(bg) =>
    box.new(0, 0, 0, 0, xloc=xloc.bar_time, border_color=na, bgcolor=bg)  // , extend=extend.right

render(boxes, index, highs, lows, times) =>
    ibox = get(boxes, index)
    top = get(highs, index)
    bottom = get(lows, index)
    left = get(times, index)
    overlapped = if index > 0
        lastbox = index - 1
        top == get(lows, lastbox) or bottom == get(highs, lastbox)
    box.set_lefttop(ibox, left, overlapped ? na : top)
    box.set_rightbottom(ibox, time, overlapped ? na : bottom)

var supply = input.color(#f2364680, 'Supply Zones')
var demand = input.color(#08998180, 'Demand Zones')

var buyBox = array.new_box(0)
var sellBox = array.new_box(0)

for i = 0 to maxbox(na(close[1]))
    array.push(buyBox, newbox(demand))
    array.push(sellBox, newbox(supply))

for i = 0 to maxbox(upturn or brokenLow)
    render(buyBox, i, buyzoneHigh, buyzoneLow, buyzoneTime)

for i = 0 to maxbox(downturn or brokenHigh)
    render(sellBox, i, sellzoneHigh, sellzoneLow, sellzoneTime)

// C. ALERTS
if brokenHigh
    alert('Breakout', alert.freq_once_per_bar)

if brokenLow
    alert('Breakdown', alert.freq_once_per_bar)

if upturn or downturn
    setup = switch
        whiteSoldiers => 'White Soldiers'
        blackCrows => 'Black Crows'
        breakHigh => bullishEngulf ? 'Engulf & Break High' : 'Break High'
        breakLow => bearishEngulf ? 'Engulf & Break Low' : 'Break Low'
        bullishEngulf => 'Bullish Engulf'
        bearishEngulf => 'Bearish Engulf'
    occurence = replace ? 'Replace' : (overlap ? 'Bounce' : 'Fresh')
    message = setup + ' (' + occurence + ')'
    alert(message, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

Comment: What is the error message you get? Please add it to the question